# MySQL query for a date field selection all entries between certain hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple records in MySQL database with one of the fields being of type datetime. I need to pull out a set of data with all records that have their time between 00:00 and 03:00, regardless of the date ahead of them. Obviously the BETWEEN clause does not work as it requires a valid date. I can't figure out how to use a regular expression either so I'm pretty much stuck on this query. Any tips?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`HOUR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

```
SELECT fields
FROM myTable
WHERE HOUR(my_date) >= 0 AND HOUR(my_date) <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Never knew about that HOUR function existed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`hour`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function to extract the hour part of a date:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  HOUR(my_date_field) BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```